# Subversion xib merge error

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, svn, interface-builder

So I don't know all that much about subversion, but I use Versions svn to keep my Xcode projects synced between my laptop and desktop and this is the first issue I've had with it. I did a bunch of work on my laptop while away over the weekend and tried to sync when I got home; however, when I committed the changes from my laptop and updated on my desktop, something weird happened. The project opens up (on my desktop computer) but gives me the following error:

```
The document "ClassInputViewController.xib" could not be opened. Could not read archive.
```

along with about 50 merge conflicts on various lines of that xib. upon closer inspection of the files, I saw that 3 new files had been added during the update that weren't in the files from my commit on the laptop: **ClassInputViewController.xib.mine**, **ClassInputViewController.xib.r101** and **ClassInputViewController.xib.r102** that Versions says aren't under version control. If I delete these files, the merge conflicts in Xcode disappear but the main "Could not read archive" error still occurs. I know one simple solution to this would be to back up the project on my laptop, delete it from svn and add back in the working files, but I'd like to figure out how to fix this is case it happens again with a bigger project that wouldn't be so easy to do that with. Anyone know what to do in this situation?

Comment: One option you have is to do an svn revert on these xibs. Otherwise you can open it in a text editer and remove the conflicts yourself if you are confident.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oooh, I saw it many times. Best solution - it's just throw away the most unserious changes.

Comment: What do you mean "throw away the most unserious changes"?

Comment: I mean just take version with most serious changes, everything else has to be redone. It'll take much less time than you'll try to solve this xml manually. You can take version for example only yours or only HEAD.

Comment: would it be possible to just revert the xib file or do I have to do the whole project?